# Displaying array with index in Dart Flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, mobile

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Column(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           children: <Widget>[
             for (var i = 0;i < snapshot.data[0]["meanings"][index]["definitions"].length;i++)
               for (var item in snapshot.data[0]["meanings"][index]["definitions"])
                 Text(
                   (i + 1).toString() + ". " + item["definition"],
                   textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                 )
           ],
         ),
       )
```

This is the result the code gives:
[image: Code Result]

[image]
I would like something like:

1. A party...
2. A hairdo
3. Something that....
   ...

List should end at 7 which is the length of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get rid of unnecessary repetition you just simply have to get rid of your nested for loop, which is totally redundant here. Access your item with loop index - `snapshot.data[0]["meanings"][index]["definitions"][i]["definition"]`

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Column(
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
           children: <Widget>[
             for (var i = 0;i < snapshot.data[0]["meanings"][index]["definitions"].length;i++)
                 Text(
                   (i + 1).toString() + ". " + snapshot.data[0]["meanings"][index]["definitions"][i]["definition"],
                   textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                 )
           ],
         ),
       )
```

Comment: Why no curly braces after for loop?

Comment: Curly braces are not used inside the build method, instead of that you just simply use indentation.